# display error icon in form using background-image

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a form that whenever someone enters information incorrectly it displays a message, I also want an error icon to appear next to the error text. I added span tags for the error message and gave it a .error icon class in CSS. I added a background-image in the selector but it is not appearing when I preview in the browser. I inspected the code and I can't even see the .error icon class in the code. I tried adding   between the span tags which was something I saw in a form in a website but that didn't work.

I am unsure of what method to use for inserting this icon as I know it is not good practice to repeat the same image src code for each section I want to apply the error icon to, hence why I am trying to use it as a background-image instead.

Here is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/HNSM4/2/

HTML

```
  <label for="name">
<span class="textStyle">Full Name*</span><input type="text" id="name"><br>
    <span id="nameMessage" class="message"><span class"erroricon"> &nbsp;</span>You must have a valid name</span>
```

CSS

```
.message{
display: none;  
}

.erroricon {
background-image:url('http://postimg.org/image/v6997l887/')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than putting the icon in a span as a background image, just make it the background image of `.message` and add padding to the left so nothing can occupy the space:

```
.message{
    display: none;  
    background: url("http://s7.postimg.org/v6997l887/erroricon.png") no-repeat;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

The image you provided is blank, so I have nothing to show you there, but you can see that the text is pushed over, and if you use inspect element, you can see that the image is loaded.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HNSM4/5/)

---

### [**Here is an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/HNSM4/4/) with the Google logo as the background image.